# Add elements to matlab cell array member variable

Tags: matlab, class, cell-array

i have a class called `sampleClass` with a cell array member variable called `list`.
Now i am trying to add elements to the internal list. For this purpose, i created the method `addToList`. The method simply tries to add elements to the `list`.

```
classdef sampleClass

    properties
        list = {}
    end

    methods
        function addToList(obj)
            obj.list{end+1}='test';
            obj.list
        end
    end

end
```

Now the problem is, that the elements are not stored in the list.
Inside the function `addToList` the following output signalizes that the element is stored in the `list`:

```
>> samp = sampleClass();
>> samp.addToList
ans = 
    'test'
```

But after leaving the function, the element is no longer accessible:

```
>> samp.list
ans = 
     {}
```

Has anybody an idea what's going wrong? I am using Matlab 7.11.0 (R2010b).
Thanks for your help.

Julien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you forgot to inherit from the `handle` class:

```
classdef sampleClass < handle %// Change here!

    properties
        list = {}
    end

    methods
        function addToList(obj)
            obj.list{end+1}='test';
            obj.list
        end
    end    
end
```

If you want to retain the changes made when modifying an instance of your class, you **must** inherit from the `handle` class.  This can be done by taking your class definition (first line of your code), and doing `< handle`.  If you don't, then any changes you make will not be saved.  To show that this works, this is what I get in MATLAB:

```
>> samp = sampleClass();
>> samp.addToList

ans = 

    'test'

>> samp.list

ans = 

    'test'
```

To be more verbose, here's what the [MATLAB docs say about `handle`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle.html):

> The handle class is the superclass for all classes that follow handle semantics. A handle is a reference to an object. If you copy an object's handle, MATLAB® copies only the handle and both the original and copy refer to the same object data. If a function modifies a handle object passed as an input argument, the modification affects the original input object.

As such, you need to inherit from the `handle` class so that you have a reference back to the object you created.  Any changes you make to the instance of your class will be remembered if you inherit from `handle`.  If you don't, no changes you make get registered.